# Google+ sign in integration code for fragment and how to call it in an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, google-plus

Recently i saw a post for google+ login integration in android app on stackoverflow '[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147950/google-integration-code-from-learnsauce-com-throwing-so-many-errors-and-build-f)' but i need to code this as a fragment and not as an activity. I went through certain sites but they just tell you to change one or two methods but the code in the link is quite long so what changes should i make to that '[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147950/google-integration-code-from-learnsauce-com-throwing-so-many-errors-and-build-f)' to code it as a fragment and how should i call that fragment from an activity ?????

My another question in context of this is when the login is successful a person gets a screen showing his profile info having name, email and a logout button so, how can we navigate from that profile info screen to next home fragment of the app (please answer in reference to the link i provided).

I'll be very grateful if u can tell me the changes that i have to make in the code to make it a fragment and how to call that fragment from the activity as am not getting clear information from surfing internet.

Thanks!! :)